# Choose k items to maximize profit

Tags: algorithm

I stumbled upon this problem and didn't have any clue on how to solve this. Can someone please help me with this?
The problem is below:

Suppose we've built a website and intended to get profit from advertisements. For every person that visits the website, the server chooses k advertisements from a set S = {1,...,n}, orders them in some way and shows them as a list.

The selection and the order to show depend on the value v(i) (v(i) is an integer) and the quality q(i) (0 <= q(i) <= 1) of each advertisement i, and the tendency t(i) (0 < t(i) < 1) to go on with the next advertisement in the list.

What will happen when a person clicks on an advertisement is as follow:

1. The person first checks out advertisement a1.
2. When he checks out advertisement a(i), he follows the link with probability q(a(i)), and we get v(a(i)) in profit.
3. Whether or not he followed the link of advertisement a(i), he continues to check out advertisement a(i+1) with probability t(a(i)) and stops checking out the advertisements with probability 1 - t(a(i))
4. If he has chosen to continue checking out advertisements, he'll finally stop when he's done with advertisement a(k).

Based on the above descriptions, our web server selects the advertisements and their order to maximize the profit. Suppose the person has checked out advertisements a1, a2, ..., a(i-1), then the probability that he checks out advertisement a(i) is:

[image]

Therefore, the server chooses the list of k advertisements to maximize the expected profit which is:

[image]

a) Show that if (a1, a2, ..., a(k)) is a list of advertisements with maximum expected profit, then:
[image]

b) Design a O(nlogn + nk) algorithm to calculate the maximum expected profit.

Comment: Unless this is some kind of scam (like the "do surveys to download pirated stuff" crap), you cannot assume that `Whether or not he followed the link of advertisement a(i), he continues to check out advertisement a(i+1) with probability t(a(i)) and stops checking out the advertisements with probability 1 - t(a(i))`.

Comment: Also more data is needed.
Is the actual profit (that is, CPC) equal? Is it expected to change on any event periodically?

Comment: @Victor I think it means the person needs to look at the ad a(i-1) before looking at the ad a(i), but he didn't have to follow the link of a(i-1). Sorry for the ambiguity. What do you mean by the actual profit being equal and change to the event?

Comment: Well, okay, but if this is not in a stepping manner, you cannot actually expect anyone "noticing" an ad, if it is not obtrusive in any manner.

Comment: @Victor I don't know, I think that's what the problem implies.

Comment: So this is not a real world problem, but some interview question or homework, right?